# how to have a variable in userform object indicator name (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a user form in VBA, and what I am looking for is to search for a specific text, when it is found, i want the textboxes to be filled from the next cells.

my code would be:

```
i = TextBox1.Value
Set orange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10000").Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If orange Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No Match Found"
Else: j = orange.Address
ka = 1
kb = 11
For k = 1 To 10
UserForm1(TextBox & kb).Value = Sheets(1).Range(j).Offset(0, ka).Value
ka = ka + 1
kb = kb + 1
Next k
```

of course `UserForm1(TextBox & kb).Value = Sheets(1).Range(j).Offset(0, ka).Value` does not work.

any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `Me` in place of the form name
- You don't need all of those counter variables - just use the loop counter
- Use the `Controls` collection to access the textboxes (passing in a string)
- Indent your code

Untested:

```
i = TextBox1.Value
Set orange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10000").Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If orange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No Match Found"
Else

    For k = 1 To 10
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & (k+10)).Value = orange.EntireRow.Cells(k).Value
    Next k

end if
```